# Route 53 for hosting different environments on multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I'm having real difficulty in getting the environments setup on 2 AWS accounts which are related to each other by the virtue of Organisation Hierarchy. My root DNS provider is *GoDaddy* which is hosting DNS record for `example.com`. We have multiple services which needs to be hosted on subdomain `services.example.com`. My setup is like:

1. **GoDaddy** -> Root DNS provider for `example.com`. Has **NS record** entries for `services.example.com` pointing to **AWS Prod Account's Hosted Zone**
2. **AWS Prod Account** -> Has Hosted Zone as `services.example.com`. Within this hosted zone I have **A Records** for production services `service1.services.example.com`, `service2.services.example.com`, etc.
3. **AWS Dev Account** -> Need a way to host environments such as **test, uat, release** on Prod account subodmain as:

**Service 1**:

- `test.service1.services.example.com`
- `uat.service1.services.example.com`
- `release.service1.services.example.com`

**Service 2**:

- `test.service2.services.example.com`
- `uat.service2.services.example.com`
- `release.service2.services.example.com`

Is there any way that I can achieve this. I have attached an image for visually simplifying this setup.
[image]

Comment: Have you considered simply having 2 separate domains one for dev and one for prod? Much easier, and you get real isolation. EG services.example-dev.com. with your setup, one dev mistake and you are affecting production potentially.

Comment: @RodrigoM hosting a different domain is always an option. However, it increases the overhead of maintaining it. If there is no choice, I have to fallback to the option of either different domain for non-prod i.e. `services.example-dev.com` or a subdomain as `service1.nonprod.services.example.com` :-)

Comment: Overheard is minimal. You have a zone is each account. The services interact with the zone the same way in each account. Complete isolation and symmetry.

Comment: @RodrigoM I take your point. If this cannot be achieved I have the option that you suggested. :-)

Comment: That said, you can do it via sub domains. Buy use prod and dev as the subdomain. Or does that break your domain name scheme.?

Answer (score 5):

Create a hosted zone for `service1.services.example.com` in Acc 2.

Note the 4 name servers that Route 53 assigns to it the new hosted zone.

Back in the `services.example.com` (master zone) on Acc 1, create a new resource record, with hostname `service1` using record type NS, and enter the 4 name servers that Route 53 assigned, in the box below.

You just delegated the `service1.services.example.com` subdomain, and any hosts and subdomains in it, to a different hosted zone, which you can now break to your heart's content, without impacting the the other records.

And just can just repeat the same process for all other services you want to delegate as well. You will end up with a new hosted zone for each service, but that is a totally fine way of doing so.

The hosted zone for the subdomain can be in the same account or a different account.

Comment: If I do this @Tobias, I will loose control of service1.services.example.com to Acc2. However, I would just like to keep service1.services.example.com in Acc1 and all other DNS access *.service1.services.example.com in Acc2. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi @kk.

Since you delegate a subdomain, the subdomain and all underlying subdomains that can be created under it, will be possible for Acc2 to be changed.

If you want to only give access for a couple of subdomains (subdomain1.service1.services.example.com) under that subdomain to be changable, then you need to create multiple zones (one for every XXX.service1.services.example.com) under that and delegate every zone. But that gets kinda messy, since you get a looot of zones and the cost of zones will increase rapidly (since every zone costs).

Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Would this approach also work for a standard separation of dev and prod? For prod we would have the standard "example.com" as the domain, and "dev.example.com" as the dev env. Set up the hosted zone in prod, include a NS record pointing to the hosted zone in dev acc, and then do dev routing in the dev acc's hosted zone?